# Comparison of Test Performance between 3 Age Groups and Existence of Co-Evolutions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, psychology

I have 3 independent age groups of children aged either 5, 6 or 7. I have tested all children, regardless of the group factor, on a number of cognitive abilities. Therefore, all children have produced raw scores for each ability.

My first hypothesis is that the evolution of those abilities follows certain developmental stages (this is suggested by a consistent increase in children's test scores with advancing age, as evidenced by a graphical analysis comparing the 3 groups' scores on all abilities). I would like to mathematically determine whether these differences in test scores do in fact exist between the 3 age groups for each ability. I would also like to determine between what ages (5 to 6 or 6 to 7) the difference in test performance is the highest for each ability, so as to be able to locate its associated developmental stage.

One possibility here would be to go for a set of Kruskal-Wallis tests comparing all 3 groups' scores for each of the abilities. Should results come back significant for any of those K-Ws, I would then go for Dunn's test to determine exactly between what pairs of groups the significant differences exist. However, in the case where Dunn would indicate significant differences between both “age 5 & 6” and “age 6 & 7”, how would I mathematically determine which of them is the “biggest”? I cannot think of anything other than graphical analysis/simply comparing the differences in a diff(X)>diff(Y) type of way.

My second hypothesis is that there may be a co-evolution between some of the abilities that are being assessed, i.e. that they have their developmental stage at roughly the same time. Therefore, I would like to pair those abilities that have their highest difference in test scores between the same ages, and mathematically determine whether those differences in test scores are related to each other.

In this instance, my biggest hurdle with regard to test selection is that it is not a repeated measures design. Else, I would have calculated the difference between the individual test scores of the age groups identified by the procedure outlined in previous paragraphs and would have correlated them to determine whether there is a relationship or not. Considering that the groups are in fact independent of each other, I feel like I cannot match individual cases and therefore cannot produce those differences.

I will be restricted to non-parametric testing due to the fact that my data violates both assumptions of normal distribution across the board and homoscedasticity.

Any suggestions on what tests to use?

Comment: "I will be restricted to non-parametric testing." Why?

Comment: Because my data violates both assumptions of normality and homoscedasticity